# how can i offset a gradient in a colorramp

Tags: node-editor

i have set a gradient with a colorramp on a cube , as you can see in the picture.
what we see is that the gradient is exactly in the middle of the object.
i want to add an offset node. so that the gradient will show up at another point on the object.
 for example the complete white part would now be in the middle. 
 or the black part would be in the middle , in stead of having the black part all the way to one side now. 
how can i do this the best way ?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the the **Mapping Node**, add it with <kbd>Shift</kbd>-<kbd>A</kbd>>*Vector*>*Mapping*

[image]

You edit the location to move it. You may have to try negative values.

Comment: i found it , it didn't work before when i tried , because i had "vector selected , in stead of "point".
one big thing i learn in blender, most of the time when a function is not working as expected, is because something is not selected in the right way ...that simple.